# Focusing button by default in android tv

Tags: android-tv

I have an Android tv Layout with two buttons:

[Buttons are not focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN3eZ.png)

I want one button to be focused by default:

[Focusing choose a TV button by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEVkc.png).

I have tried a few methods.

In java file

```
final Buttonspinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.choose_folder);
                    spinner.requestFocus();
                    spinner.setFocusable(true);
```

In xml

```
android:state_focused="true"
```

Still, it's not getting focused by default.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In code:

```java
spinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
spinner.setFocusable(true);
spinner.setFocusedByDefault(true);
spinner.requestFocus();
```

Alternatively in XML:

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/choose_folder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/choose"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusedByDefault="true">
    <requestFocus/>
</Button>
```

Maybe a bit overkill, but either one of these should cover all bases.